# URL REDIRECT TO FILE

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure properly an Apache 2.4

I need that when a user gives like URL any of the next URL, example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), http://example.com, http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com it must be converted, rewrite, like https://www.example.com/xls/f?p=1589.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here is the documentation for url rewriting with mod_rewrite : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks Shim-Sao, I know this, and read and test, about documentation what Im looking for is a place where they teach you with good documented examples

Comment: Maybe this : https://support.hostgator.com/articles/apache-mod_rewrite-and-examples and this https://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com can help more with specific implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote here just an example :

```
# Redirect domain to ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Result :
http://example.com/path?variables... => https://www.example.com/path?variables...

Comment: I was watching the same example in the link that you send me.

Comment: But the question  where comes $1 ? and I suppose that $1 value is the path, "path?variables" but the question is where do you define $1 ?

Comment: $1 is a magic buffered value from current rewrite directive. The first value encountered.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [OR]

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [OR]RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [OR]RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [OR]

Comment: I will try to do in another way, I wil send you the answer because the edition in this is really bad, every time I key enter it send the message

Comment: You can write in a separate way with each domain/subdomain or like you write here and what is in the official documention : domain1 [OR] domain2... (simplified for comment)

Comment: Matbe you want this : RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example.com$ => with or without www.